# TDengine database nodejs connector millisecond precision

Tags: node.js, tdengine

I want to retrieve data from TDengine database using nodejs connector.

```
const taos = require('td2.0-connector');
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 6030;
var conn = taos.connect({host: host, user: "root", password: "taosdata", port: port});
var cursor = conn.cursor();
cursor.execute('create database if not exists demo');
cursor.execute('use demo');
cursor.execute('create table if not exists t1 (ts timestamp, _int int);');
cursor.execute('insert into t1 values(1627894963923, 0)');
cursor.execute('select * from t1');
cursor.fetchall();
console.log(Date.parse(cursor.data[0][0]));
```

but the result is [image]
, which miss the last three digits(millisecond precision). It's weird because I can still see the timestamp within shell [image]

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
Date.parse(cursor.data[0][0])
```

to

```
Date.parse(cursor.data[0][0].toISOString())
```